# nhibernate LazyLoad after Transaction commit

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, lazy-loading

What happens if I access a "lazyLoad" property of an object after I have commited the transaction (opened for search selection of the object) with nHibernate?

In my testcase this works without any sign off an error, but is this ok or smells it?

It comes from an WF Implementation, where the first action selects the object to process and later on in other actions perhaps access some lazyload Properties (attachments, ...)

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if I access a "lazyLoad" property of an object after I
>   have commited the transaction (opened for search selection of the
>   object) with nHibernate?

When access object having lazyLoad property after completion of transaction, there is new implicit transaction started for loading this object.

> In my testcase this works without any sign off an error, but is this
>   ok or smells it?

Sometimes you do not get collection in return result that time you have to load these objects after completion of query. e.g. you have set mapped of referenced class like attachments.

Comment: so it seems to be ok at a technical point of view, but architecturally it is questionable...the main aspect seems to be a clear transaction design for the application